# Which emoji is  burger's match?

Tags: cipher, visual, emoji

Known matches:

| Key | Matched |
| --- | --- |
|  |  |
|  |  |
| ❤️ | ❣️ |
|  |  |
|  |  |
|  |  |
|  |  |
|  |  |
|  |  |
|  |  |
|  |  |

What is my match, if I am ?

Hint, since I don't believe in torture

> the solution is based on the emojis' encoding - not on their meaning.

Comment: I reckon the hint was unnecessary, I would go the hinted way anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the key is  (unicode U+1F354), then the match should be

> The strawberry emoji  (unicode U+1F353)

Explanation:

> For most of the key-match pairs, the match's unicode value is 1 less than the key's unicode value, in hexadecimal. 
>  key  (U+1F643), match  (U+1F642)
>  key ❤️ (U+2764), match ❣️ (U+2763) 
>  key  (U+1F438), match  (U+1F437) 
>  key  (U+1F40D), match  (U+1F40C) 
>  key  (U+1F353), match  (U+1F352) 
>  key   (U+1F446), match  (U+1F445) 
>  key  (U+1F41F), match  (U+1F41E) 
>  key  (U+1F625), match  (U+1F624) 
>  
>  There are a few exceptions, but I could find no other pattern. Maybe these are mistakes, or are mixed up due to localization issues. 
>  key  (U+1F923), match  (U+1F91D) 
>  key  (U+1F914), match  (U+1F90E) 
>  key  (U+1F680), match  (U+1F64F)

Comment: This was my first guess as well... would be disappointing if a puzzle based on the encoding of the emojis had the wrong encoding for three of them, though.

Comment: So this is correct even though it's not correct for some? That's where I got stuck as well. What  am I missing with the math?